# Is there a data type/structure that can: hold a list of numbers, is hashable, unordered, and allows duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, set, hashable

Was looking at this [Difference between tuples and frozensets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422409/difference-between-tuples-and-frozensets-in-python) and led me to this question for my problem

Essentially I want a data type that is like a tuple, but unordered, or like a frozenset but allows duplicates (I realize by definition sets cant do that but I just am explaining what I want): hashable, unordered, duplicates allowed.

I am trying to make a set of this type of data for checking distinct values like (1,2,3) should be seen as the same as (1,3,2). I know one solution would be to use a list, order it, and then make it a tuple but I have to do this many times and the tuple length could be long so i'd rather not have to sort every time if possible.

EDIT:

problem has changed slightly. now I have a list of tuples so for example:
list_tuple = [(2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1)]

the problem has not changed much though, the tuples have an order that matters, but the order of the tuples do not. so for example this is identical to the previous one:
[(2, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1),(2, 2, 2)]
I will be getting a lot of these that I want to add to a set so I can count the number of distinct lists of tuples. so really i have the same problem of order not mattering and duplicates allowed, except instead of ints we are dealing with tuples.

I supposed I should just sort the list of tuples, then make the list a tuple and it can go in the set and work properly. I know I said i didnt want to sort but I dont see another way.

Thanks

Comment: You could check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267781/hashable-data-structure-with-no-order-and-allowed-duplicates

Comment: So basically you want an immutable [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: @Aran-Fey:Sounds to me more like a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) which AFAIK isn't in any of the standard modules (or a built-in).

Comment: A Counter basically is a multiset; it just doesn't store each object explicitly, but rather a count that indicates how many times you would need to include the object in an iteration over the elements. There's little meaningful difference between `{{'a', 'a', 'b'}}` (to make up a syntax for multistep) and `Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1})`.

Comment: @chepner: That's true, I suppose. FWIW, there's a `multiset` module on [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/multiset/).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you can wrap a `Counter` object in a `MappingProxyType`, which provides you read-only access to the underlying `Counter`.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from types import MappingProxyType
>>> d1 = MappingProxyType(Counter("aab"))
>>> d2 = MappingProxyType(Counter("aba"))
>>> d1 == d2
True
```

As far as I know, there is no way to get a reference to the underlying `Counter` objects so that you could modify them.

You just need to do a little work to iterate over the duplicates; fortunately, the `itertools` module does most of the heavy lifting.

```
>>> from itertools import chain, startup, repeat
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, d1.items())))
['a', 'a', 'b']
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, d2.items())))
['a', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, check my edit. The counter would work to represent my data, but then i need to add it into a set because I want to count the number of distinct list of tuples. but Counter isnt hashable and either is MappingProxyType as for as I can tell. I said at first I didnt want to sort but maybe thats the only option, sort the list of tuples, make the list of tuples a tuple of tuples, and then add it to the set. That would cover my case but let me know if you think theres a better way to do that

Comment: I don't see why you need `Counter` or `MappingProxyType` to be hashable. `MappingProxyType(Counter([(2,2,2), (2,2,1), (2,2,2)]))`.

Comment: I may be missing what MappingProxyType is doing for me but  Counter([(2,2,2), (2,2,1), (2,2,2)]) is just one instance I will a have lets say a bunch of these and I need to count distinct. Adding them to a set seems like it would be the most efficient way to do this as opposed to a list where i gotta check if its in there. since iirc its like O(n) for list but O(1) for sets hence why I want it hashable. sorry if im just not understanding

Comment: OK, I see, your changed problem is quite different now. I though you were going from multisets of (say) `int`s to multisets of tuples, but you are going from multisets of tuples to multisets of multisets of tuples.

Comment: yes exactly. i could just sort the individual groups of tuples in the list and then make that a tuple then i can just use a set()... probably doing this overcomplicated anyways. didnt wanna list the problem im solving cuz i wanted to try to figure it out on my own but basically trying to find unique subtrees in terms of its shape. so im trying to somehow turn the shape of a tree into the most simple representation i can which ive had some trouble with. (2,2,2), (2,2,1), (2,2,2) means the root is has 2 children and each tuple is a path from the route out represented by it # of children